# How to overcome Athena/glue varchar limit when using COPY command from parquet

Tags: pandas, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, parquet, amazon-athena

I think I have a very peculiar case. I have been trying different approaches, but nothing worked yet.

My goal: write a pandas df to redshift
My data frame: 10 columns, 2 of which have data in json format and are pretty long (more than 65535, which is the max varchar length in redshift ).
The only redshift data type that would support this 2 columns is **"super"**.

Now in the past I have tried to use **awswrangler.redshift.copy()**. This method creates a parquet file in S3 and them from there it writes the file in a redshift table, inferring automatically the data types. You can use a parameter to explicitly set the columns data types, but you have to choose from Athena/Glue types. They don't have a "super" type. They have "struct" or "array" but that does not work either.

So now instead of using awswrangler.redshif.copy(), I  execute a sql statement to redshift and create the table with the datatypes I want (i.d. 2 of the 10 columns now are correctly set to "super").
The problem comes when I have to write to that table.
In order to write data in that table I still have to save the df to a parquet file in S3 first. To do that I am using **awswrangler.s3.to_parquet()**, with the parameter dataset=True.
Once I save the file there, I run a COPY command

`f"COPY schema.table from s3path IAM_ROLE FORMAT PARQUET SERIALIZETOJSON`

When I do this I still have the following error

{'S': 'ERROR', 'C': 'XX000', 'M': 'String value exceeds the max size of 65535 bytes

I don't understand. The column that I am writing to now is a super column. Does it have to do with the fact that the copy command first create a table in Glue?
Does anyone known of a way to overcome this limit ?

Comment: Athena and Redshift are different technologies.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to reproduce your issue using this dataframe, which has `b.value` longer than 65536.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 3}],
        "b": [{"value": "a" * 66000}, {"value": "b" * 66000}, {"value": "c" * 66000}],
    }
)
```

While the dataframe below works, which doesn't have any attribute longer than 65536.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 3}],
        "b": [{"value": "a"*33000, "value2": "a"*33000},
              {"value": "b"*33000, "value2": "b"*33000},
              {"value": "c"*33000, "value2": "c"*33000}]
    }
)
```

Converting to Parquet

```
wr.s3.to_parquet(df=df, path=f"s3://{bucket}/{prefix}/testing.parquet", index=False)
```

COPY to Redshift

```
COPY public.testing from 's3://xxx' IAM_ROLE 'xxx' FORMAT PARQUET SERIALIZETOJSON
```

Comment: yes thank Isc! any idea on a potential solution?

Comment: If the finding is true, you’ll have to make the problematic attribute into multiple shorter attributes.

Comment: This statement aligns with my finding:

> An individual value within a SUPER object is limited to the maximum length of the corresponding Amazon Redshift type. For example, a single string value loaded to SUPER is limited to the maximum VARCHAR length of 65535 bytes.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/limitations-super.html